# How to stop running selenium tests AFTER webdriver.quit()?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, c#, selenium-webdriver, chrome

I have made a Windows Forms app to host my GUI for running selenium tests.

When the user presses the "run test" button, it launches an instance of chromedriver and runs the selected selenium test.

However, let's say that while the test is running, the user decides they want to stop the test, or simply not have the entire test run.

I have a button on the form that calls FixtureTearDown() in case this were to happen. FixtureTearDown is simply:

```
if (_driver != null) _driver.Quit();
```

However, if you DO press this "stop test" button, the driver closes, but the selenium test keeps executing the script as if the webdriver were still open, which then throws errors (because it can't find elements because the driver is closed, duh) and causes my Windows Forms app to crash.

So, is there a way to gracefully halt the running of a selenium script? Thanks in advance for the help, and i apologize if this is a dumb question, i am still new to selenium and c# in general.

Comment: I have never seen the browser remain open after `driver.quit()`. Which browser are you using? Are you sure your button click event quits the driver?

Comment: The driver and the test scripts are different things. Yes, with driver.quit() you close the driver. But the test script is still running. So you need to stop the test itself. This can be managed by the testing framework that you are using. It should provide a solution to stop a started test script.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I solved it, but it might not be best practice.

Basically, in each test method I assign that method to a current thread variable.

```
targetThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
```

and then, when the user presses the stop test button, I kill the thread. It works like a charm.

```
public void haltScript()
{
    targetThread.Abort();
}
```

of course, I'm quitting the driver also, but this seems to work for stopping the execution of the script.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `driver.close()` and `driver.quit()` both in the end.

driver.close – It closes the the browser window on which the focus is set.

driver.quit – It basically calls driver.dispose method which in turn closes all the browser windows and ends the WebDriver session gracefully.

[Reference](http://www.testingdiaries.com/driver-close-and-driver-quit/)

Comment: Short answers without explanation do not really help, can you explain why this would help? Also from what I read here .quit() will close all the windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15067107/difference-between-webdriver-dispose-close-and-quit

Comment: I don't think you can `driver.quit()` after `driver.close()`. From what  remember, it throws an exception.

Comment: It is also a way but If you want to kill driver process then both required.

Comment: I may mis-understand but .quit() method has already include .close() method, right?

Comment: @NamGVU If you use one browser then only quite() is better option.

Comment: I don't think it'good choice to use the same variable e.g. driver for two different browsers or webdriver objects. Each browser has its own webdriver class and should has its own webdriver object.

Comment: @Sagar007 If you directly quote a resource like you did [with these definitions](http://www.testingdiaries.com/driver-close-and-driver-quit/), please provide a link. However, the point of that link is that `driver.quit` needs to be called, not that `driver.close` should be called first. You should only use `driver.close` if you intend to close the current window, but you want to continue running tests on other windows under the same driver. If you have multiple windows and want to close them all at the end of your test, you use `driver.quit`

Comment: @mrfreester Can you please explain or put your point more broadly ? I did not get a single meaning by your comment regarding link.

Comment: @Sagar007 I see you've edited your answer to add the reference, thank you :) That's all I meant. If you quote a resource it's good to add the reference. Cheers :) If your question was in regards to the `close` vs. `quit`, I was just stating that if you use `quit` you don't need to call `close` first, because `quit` will close the windows before cleaning up the driver.